# Java: how to get the abs value of a short and keep it short

Tags: java, math, type-conversion

```
Short s = somevalue; // could be negative or positive
myobject.setMyShort(Math.abs(s));
```

I can't change the type of field myShort of MyObject, at the same time Math.abs return only int values.
Is it right to cast this way or could it result in a change of the original value?

```
myobject.setMyShort((short) Math.abs(s));
```

Comment: If your short value is `Short.MIN_VALUE`, then `Math.abs(s)` will be `32768`, which is outside of the range of `short`. When you cast it to a short, you will get `-32768` instead. Other than that, you're fine.

Answer (score 2):

It's correct way - if you are sure that your argument is short - it will be safely casted then.

Comment: right forgot about Short.MIN_VALUE exception - in this case it will be incorrect...

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be write your `Math.abs()` method, the code is much cleaner:

```
public abstract class MathUtils {
    public static short absShort(short a){
        return a > 0 ? a : -a;
    }
}
```

Comment: why cleaner? everyone knows what abs mean and don't need to see the implementation like that

Comment: Because you don't have to cast to int and back to short which is cleaner.

Comment: This will also have the similar problem related to Short.MIN_VALUE